# UCanAccess Select statement with Numeric Wildcards giving unexpected token: REGEXP_MATCHES required

Tags: java, ucanaccess

I have a Query in access that seems to only work with the * wildcard but not the # wildcard.

So I want to exclude all records where T[5 digits] are in [Field1] Before, I just used **T*** I created a query in access named Query and put this in the SQL design

**Query1**

```
Select [Field1], [Field2], [Table2].[Field3] from [Table1] 
LEFT JOIN [Table1] ON [Table1].[Field1] = [Table2].[Field1] 
where [Field1] NOT LIKE "T*"
```

**Java Code**

```
try(PreparedStatement s = conn.prepareStatement("Select [Field1], [Field2], [Field3] from [Query1] where [Field2] 
BETWEEN ? AND ?")){
s.setDate(1,java.sql.Date.valueOf(df.getValue()));
s.setDate(2,java.sql.Date.valueOf(dfEnd.getValue()));
try(ResultSet rs = s.executeQuery()){ .... etc etc}
```

THIS WORKS PERFECTLY.

However now, I need to be more specific, and exclude field1 data with **T#####**

So I tried to change my query saved in my Access like so:

**Query1:**

```
Select [Field1], [Field2], [Table2].[Field3] from [Table1] 
LEFT JOIN [Table1] ON [Table1].[Field1] = [Table2].[Field1] 
where [Field1] NOT LIKE "T#####"
```

In Access, this pulls up a query just fine, no issues in Access from what I can see.

But if I use the same code in Java, copied and pasted, I get this error:

> UCAExc:::4.0.2 user lacks privilege or object not found: QUERY1

I tried Compact and repair, same error. I change T##### back to T* and the error is gone.

So... I tried to work around it by going directly for the tables, so in Java I used

**Javacode:**

```
 Select [Field1], [Field2], [Table2].[Field3] from [Table1] 
LEFT JOIN [Table1] ON [Table1].[Field1] = [Table2].[Field1] 
where [Field1] NOT LIKE \"T####\" AND [Field2] BETWEEN ? AND ?")){
s.setDate(1,java.sql.Date.valueOf(df.getValue()));
s.setDate(2,java.sql.Date.valueOf(dfEnd.getValue()));
try(ResultSet rs = s.executeQuery()){ .... etc etc}
```

And this time, I get

> UCAExc:::4.0.2 unexpected token: REGEXP_MATCHES required:

I'm unsure where to go from here. My question is why will it not accept ## is this a UCanAccess issue? A java issue? A permissions issue? Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to reproduce your issue. Under UCanAccess 4.0.2 this works:

```sql
SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE Field1 LIKE "T#####"
```

but this fails:

```sql
SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE Field1 NOT LIKE "T#####"
```

However, this workaround seems to be okay:

```sql
SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE NOT (Field1 LIKE "T#####")
```